# Check items if is in list or not and remove old items

Tags: c#, logic

I have a list. When this list populate, I've got somethings like that:

```
List<T> {Soc1, Soc2, Soc3}
```

with Soc complex object. Then I modify the list: delete Soc2, add Soc4:

```
List<T> {Soc1, Soc3, Soc4}
```

Now, on db, I've got the first list (1,2,3) and I must update with the new one (1,3,4). How to do this check in c#? I try to use the List method contains

```
foreach(T t in oldList){
if(t.Contains(oldList)){
...}
```

for add the new item(s), but I stop on the remove of element that not exist anymore (Soc2 in this example). How to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

foreach will break when you modify the list (delete an item). Therefore it's better to use while instead.
You use a while for the old list to remove the elements which don't exist anymore and afterwards a foreach trough the new list to add the new items.

```
List<T> oldList = new List<T> { Soc1, Soc2, Soc3 };
List<T> newList = new List<T> { Soc1, Soc3, Soc4 };

int i = 0;
// Go trough the old list to remove items which don't exist anymore
while(i < oldList.Count)
{
    // If the new list doesn't contain the old element, remove it from the old list
    if (!newList.Contains(oldList[i]))
    {
        oldList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    // Otherwise move on
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}

// Now go trough the new list and add all elements to the old list which are new
foreach(T k in newList)
{
    if (!oldList.Contains(k))
    {
        oldList.Add(k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do two loops and use LINQ:

```
// add the new ones...
foreach (var newItem in newList.Where(n => !oldList.Any(o => o.Id == n.Id))) {
    oldList.Add(newItem);
}

// remove the redundant ones...
var oldIds = oldList.Select(i => i.Id);
foreach (var oldId in oldIds) {
    if (!newList.Any(i => i.Id == oldId)) {
        oldList.Remove(oldList.First(i => i.Id == oldId));
    }
}
```